# WSL SSH in VS Code: Bad configuration option: c:\\windows\\system32\\wsl.exe

Tags: visual-studio-code, ssh, windows-subsystem-for-linux

I'm trying to run SSH through my WSL instance in VS Code. I'm doing this by pointing to a bat file containing the line `C:\Windows\system32\wsl.exe ssh %*` as described here: https://zitseng.com/archives/20325 . However, in VS Code when trying to connect, I'm receiving the following error:

```
[12:16:18.548] Using SSH config file "C:\Users\[user]\.ssh\ssh.bat"
[12:16:18.549] Running script with connection command: "C:\WINDOWS\System32\OpenSSH\ssh.exe" -T -D 55283 -F "C:\Users\[user]\.ssh\ssh.bat" "[server name]" bash
[12:16:18.551] Terminal shell path: C:\WINDOWS\System32\cmd.exe
[12:16:18.823] > C:\\Users\\[user]\\.ssh\\ssh.bat: line 1: Bad configuration option: c:\\windows\\system32\\wsl.exe
> C:\\Users\\[user]\\.ssh\\ssh.bat: terminating, 1 bad configuration options
> The process tried to write to a nonexistent pipe.
```

The configuration file has been changed to the location of the bat file, so it's not that. When I try to connect from the terminal in my VS Code WSL instance it works just fine, also. Any ideas?

I can't *not* use WSL, or make a copy of my public and private key, because I'm also using a secondary verification that only works on Linux. I'd also rather not dual-boot Linux, if possible.